# cannot uninstall fcitx without causing a login loop

Tags: login, input, fcitx

SO I was playing around with different pinyin (chinese input) options and one of them required me to install fcitx so I did. I ended up not wanting to use it so I uninstalled it...

```
sudo apt-get remove fcitx
```

after I did that I started a login loop (after I type my password the screen goes back and then redirects me back to the unity login page) on the next restart and it took me forever to figure out that that was the problem. I solved it by getting to a shell and re-installing fcitx and I was able to login again.

I tried setting my preferred input method to iBus but that doesnt do anything. How can I fix this problem? I have no idea where to start looking

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue after uninstalling fcitx from Ubuntu 14.04.

I am giving you the main steps as I remember them.

**A) Fix the boot loop first:**

1. at login screen type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd> .. <kbd>F6</kbd>)
2. you will enter a terminal in full black screen. From there you install `fcitx` AGAIN by

   ```
    sudo apt-get install fcitx
   ```
3. Go back to the normal login screen and now log in into your account

**B) Uninstall fcitx cleanly:**

1. Refer to [this manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20220703235515/http://codepub.cn/2015/11/27/Ubuntu14-10-install-and-uninstall-sogou-input-method/) with Google translator.
2. Open terminal again and you only need following commands:

   ```
    sudo dpkg -l so*

    sudo apt-get purge sogoupinyin

    sudo apt-get purge fcitx

    sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
3. Restart your computer.